# Issues with AltSoftSerial

Tags: serial, softwareserial

I have my arduino connected to my PC and another serial device.
This serial device sends a 3 line piece of info on bootup then if I trip a zone it will send information regarding the radio transmission.

When I first power up the device I see the information from the device in the serial monitor (SELFTEST-PASS) however that is the last information I receive from it until I powercycle the device.

I have connected it directly to my PC comport and verified information is being sent via Serial however the arduino seems to quit after the first bit of info... any idea where to proceed from here?
PS I have tried both SoftwareSerial and NewSoftSerial
Here is an example of the data sent from the serial device as viewed by hyperterminal:

```
<1234 #3F->0000 1234->FFFF D_ALARM>
<FFFF #3F->1234 FFFF->1234 P_ACK>
<1234 #40->0000 1234->FFFF D_ZREST>
```

Code that is currently not working:

```
 #include <AltSoftSerial.h>
 AltSoftSerial portOne;

void setup() {


                Serial.begin(4800);
                while (!Serial) {; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
                }
                // Start each software serial port
                portOne.begin(4800);

              }

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() 
{
  if (portOne.available())
  {
    Serial.write(portOne.read());
  }

  if (Serial.available())
  {
    portOne.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: What pin do you have the device connected to on the Arduino? What Arduino do you have? What baud rate do you have set in the Serial Monitor?

Comment: 8,9 - uno 4800.   When I first power up unit is see the self test but nothing further. I have connected directly to a pic and verified the radio I'm connecting to does indeed continue to send data.

Comment: Which is Rx and which is Tx?

Comment: One way displayed junk when I booted up the device so I swapped the pins and that showed me the bootup message. 9=tx 8=rx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device connected to arduino had DTR/DSR. I had to jumper one to the other to convince it to flow data to the arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Try SoftwareSerial rather than AltSoftSerial.

I don't see the point in these lines, I think you can remove them:

```
 if (Serial.available())
  {
    portOne.write(Serial.read());
  }
```

---

> I have connected directly to a pic and verified the radio I'm connecting to does indeed continue to send data.

If that is the case, that it sends data anyway, then you could just use HardwareSerial. Connect the radio to Rx (D0 on the Uno) and leave Tx unconnected. Then just read from Serial, and write to Serial. You should see the results on the Serial Monitor. (Disconnect this wire when uploading new versions of the sketch).

Comment: Thank you for the information Nick, in my original post I stated I had tried both SoftwareSerial and AltSoftSerial.  Also I believe the snippet of code you specified allows me to send a character from the serial monitor to the serial device hooked up to the software serial port... Yes?

Comment: Yes, but does the device need to receive data?

Comment: I can trigger a response from the radio but sending a character to it. However I am not seeing anything after the initial boot up message. I can connect directly to of serial and interact np, but the arguing only gives me the initial power up message.

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: Now I'm totally stumped.

Comment: This works the same way, I put in code as you stated, I still see the power on message but no following messages. I've plugged in another serial monitor and verified the serial data is being sent and it is but when I plug in the device to the arduino I get the bootup and nothing else.  Serial parameters are 4800 8-N-1 Flow: Off

Comment: Seems like there must be something different about the arduino serial compared to the PC serial.... I can't figure it out. I can unplug it from the arduino and directly into my computer and see the data flow but then hook it into the arduino and nothing.

Comment: Serial input is "passive". The sending device doesn't know if you are receiving or not (ie. the Rx pin is high impedance). So either it stops sending (for some reason) or you are receiving but somehow ignoring it. `I can trigger a response from the radio but sending a character to it.` - well, send a character to it then. Try going back to AltSoftwareSerial, and send a newline or something every few seconds.

Comment: I went back on looked at the Device, it has 6 pins, GND, RX, TX, DTR DSR +12v (supplied from device)
I put a jumper between DTR and DSR and suddenly I see the information streaming. I'm guessing i need to hook that to the arduino somehow so I can interupt the DTR and then send my character then turn the DSR back on... Thank you for persevering on this with me.

Comment: Can't you leave them jumpered? In the olden days we used to just jumper stuff together until it worked. It's not as if you are looking at DTR/DSR anyway.

Comment: Nick, After more research yes your right it appears I can just leave it jumpered. I can now see all the information from the information. The next step is I need to pass the letter d to the arduino. When I have the device connected to hyperterminal I press 'd' and nothing else and it gives me a status report... I've tried a hundred different things but can't seem to get this part going. should I open a new question so I can post the code? I'm pretty new here.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a different question. Can you please take steps to let the Stack Exchange system know this question is answered? Either accept my answer, or post your *own* answer to your question along the lines of: `Problem solved by jumpering together DTR/DSR` - that way the next person with this problem will find a solution here.